# AutoHotkey Right Alt + Shift doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, arrow-keys

I have made an Autohotkey script that presses left when pressed RightAlt + j and the other arrow keys in a similar way, similar to how you can move with HJKL in vim, except that everything is shifted one key to the right and you have to press RightAlt (I'm using the US qwerty keyboard scheme, hence I have no AltGr) because I got annoyed of reaching out to the bottom right of the keyboard for the arrow keys.

So, this works, I can press RightAlt + j to move right and k, l and ; for the other arrow keys. However, I want to support Shift + RightAlt + j, so that I can easily select text with those keybindings. That's why I made this:

```
>!+j::Send {+Left}
```

However, when I try to do this, it simply does nothing. It does't send j, it doesn't send left, it just does nothing.
What's wrong with this and how can I fix it?

Comment: The right syntax is `Send +{Left}`

Comment: Ah thanks. Also, what would be the right syntax of `Send {+Left down}`? `Send +{Left down}`?

Comment: {Left down} only makes sense in the SendEvent command: `SendEvent {Shift Down}{Left down}{Shift Up}{Left Up}`. The best [SendMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm) in most cases is [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You just put the shift modifier (`+`) inside the brackets, when it should be outside. This code should work.

```
>!+j::Send +{Left}
```